Standard logic app workflow URL does not show after deploying with ARM template to different resource group
I have resource group A with a standard logic app and a few workflows.
Few of the workflows have a HTTP trigger and in the overview section the URL field is filled in.
When I deploy all those workflows with the ARM template from Azure Devops to a different resource group (all the other details are also edited in the deployment), the URL field is not filled in anymore.
What is the best way to deploy those workflows under a different resource group with the URl field filled in?
As you can see is the Workflow URL empty. In the original resource group the field is not empty.

This is the task I am using to deploy the logic app.
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: "Create Standard Logic Application"
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: $(TestSubscription)
    subscriptionId: $(IDTestSubscription)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/logicapp_deployment.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/logicapp_parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    overrideParameters: '-SubscriptionName $(TestSub) -VersionToDeploy $(VersionToDeploy) -LaName $(LaName) -LaStorageAccountName $(LaStorageAccountName)'
  continueOnError: true

This is the task I am using to deploy the workflows.
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1 
  displayName: Deploy Logic App Workflows
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: Testsubscription
    appType: functionapp 
    appName: $(LaAppName)
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/workflow.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
    ResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
  continueOnError: true


Can you share the template to check the issue. @Sergio

@Jahnavi Do you want to see the logicapp deployment template or the task I am using in the YAML file to deploy the workflows? I have added the workflow task for now.

workflow task is fine. I need to check the logicapp deployment template. Can you share that as well. @Serigo

It's the matter of your logicapp deployment template.  you need to integrate the logicapp workflow child resource, such as http trigger in the arm template. It's not easy to find offical samples code for this.

@Jahnavi do you have experience with the http trigger child resource?

Manually you can add a parameter for callback URL in the arm template and then add it in the Devops agent. Is that works for you! @Sergio

I suppose you're using a different storage account as well? Are you using VNet?

@10p at this moment I am not using VNET. The storage account is in the same resource group. it is the storage account which belongs to the logic app.

When I deployed Azure Logic app workflow in standard logic app, Even the workflow was not visible. But the workflow triggers ran successfully. As an alternative I deployed the below ARM Template code for consumption based plan and the Workflow URL was visible after deployment:-
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "actions": {
            "HTTPRequest": {
              "type": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
              },
              "runAfter": {}
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "manualTrigger": {
              "type": "Request",
              "kind": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "method": "POST",
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "parameters": {},
        "state": "Enabled"
      }
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "http-trigger-logicapp",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of the Logic App."
      }
    }
  }
}

Output:-

Try using the yaml code below to deploy the Workflow:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy files to artifact staging directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **/*.json
      !**/bin/**
      !**/obj/**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy logic app workflows'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxxxxxcb2a7)'
    appType: 'functionApp'
    appName: 'valleyLA98'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'


thank you for your answer, but this looks like a consumption logic app. I am deploying the standard logic app workflow. Or is this the way it will work for the standard logic app workflow?
